# Click Event Closure Inside Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, closures

I have a click event attached to an element via JQuery in a loop (loop variable i):

```
$('#id_'+i).click(function() {ItemClick(i)});
```

And defined somewhere else:

```
function ItemClick(x) {
    alert(x);
}
```

As expected, this doesn't work as expected, because of the closure. I'd like to see a different number shown for each different click event, instead I just get the last value of i.

I know I need to turn the i in the closure to something that somehow isn't attached to the scope of the closure, but it eludes me, even after trying various examples. Such as:

```
$('#id_'+i).click(function() {ItemClick(function(x){return x)(i))});
```

Is there a neat and concise way of doing this?

**EDIT**

After looking at the duplicate, I now have two answers (please close the question):

*Answer A*

```
$('#id_'+i).data('index',i);

$('#id_'+i).click(
    function() {
        ItemClick($(this).data('index'));
    }
);
```

*Answer B*

```
$('#id_'+i).click(
    function(index) {
        return function () {
            ItemClick(index)
        };
    }(i)
);
```

Comment: Don't use incremental `id` attributes. It leads to headaches like this. Use a common class, and access them by index, or if needed, add an identifier in a `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common javascript issue that occurs because Javascript is `closure/scope` based, not `block` based.

You can fix this by creating a `closure` around your function call.

```
$('#id_' + i).on('click', function() {
    (function (index) { 
        ItemClick(index);
    }(i));
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mKMUZ/)**

Comment: I'd like to accept this answer. But I'm afraid it doesn't work. I still get the last value of i in the click.

Comment: Oh I apologize, it should be `ItemClick(index)` ! Fixing it now